# Messaging how to get the Delivery Status Callback to be called?

Tags: messaging

I'm using Messages to send a SMS, this is working fine. I have configured the "Delivery Status Callback" in Messaging, Services, "MY SERVICE NAME", Integration but the callback is not being fired. I have manually tested the Call back url from a browser and that works ok. What am I missing?

Comment: The web app is listening for both GET and POST.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not code to share as such. I am using a Node-Red "HTTP in" Node that just listens for GET/POST requests.

Comment: I'm assuming there is some additional configuration, over and above what I have detailed that I am missing or some option on the original json parameters for the REST API call that is required to request delivery status but I cant find it.